# Removing non-printing characters from XML text (or any string)

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm getting an XML document back from a company and it has embedded tabs, newlines and other non-printing garbage in it. Is there some method in the framework that will take such a string and remove these unwanted characters? Some screenshots below, these are not debugger/visualiser artefacts as they are actually coming into play when I do string compares

**Example #1:**

[image: Example screenshot #1]

**Example #2:**

[image: Example screenshot #2]

FWIW these XML documents come from UTF8 encoding the response to a web request.

**EDIT 2014-09-03 20:20 IST**

In response to comments below from @CodeCaster I upload values (in the form of a `NameValueCollection`) using an instance of a `WebClient`. The `response` comes back to me and I do the following:

```
string reply = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
XmlNamespaceManager xmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(reply);
```

It is this `xmlDocument` that has the offending characters throughout

Comment: System.String.Replace() seems like a good choice.

Comment: _"I'm getting an XML document"_ - please show that code. - @Jay no, not really, the non-printable characters may be legit in certain places.

Comment: for clarification I did not want to suggest using string replace on the xml document. Use it on the content of the nodes when you consume the document.

Comment: sometimes using XDocument.Parse() works when XMLDocument.Load() doesnt work.

Comment: Do you want tabs to result in at least one space between words? Newlines? Tossing "non-printing garbage" may not be what you really want. Or just use `String.RemoveUnwanted(mindRead: 42);`.

Comment: If they always come at the beginning and end of the string, you can simply use `String.Trim()`.

Comment: @CodeCaster See expansion of question above, HTH

Comment: @Jay So today it's tabs and newlines, String.Replace will need to be called for each type of non-printing character

Comment: @HABO String.RemoveUnwanted() sounds cool! Coming in v5 of the framework I hear ;-) See the date string above in #2 and note how there's a space between the date and time portions of it? That'd be a specific example of something I'd want to leave while removing the newlines and tabs

Comment: @wdosanjos I'm not sure if they only come at the beginning and the end of the string. In the two examples above they do so this could the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a trivial task for XSLT.

This XSLT stylesheet normalizes (removes excessive whitespace from) all text nodes from the input XML document, leaving everything else untouched.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Use the [`XslCompiledTransform` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform(v=vs.110).aspx) to apply it to your input XML.

---

Be aware that whitespace may sometimes carry meaning. Clobbering all of it might be counter-productive.

When in doubt, adapt the match expression (`<xsl:template match="text()">`) to something more specific (like `<xsl:template match="message//text()">` or `<xsl:template match="status/text()">`) to affect only those text nodes that you *really* want to straighten out.

---

Of course you can achieve the same effect by applying a regular expression to the offending string value after you extracted it from the document:

```
return Regex.Replace(value, @"\s+", " ").Trim();
```

Using XSLT to clean up the input XML up-front in one step might be more convenient.

Comment: I apologise for the delay in accepting this but I put a hack in place to get around this issue. On revisiting it I used the core of the idea in this really great answer. Thanks for the time taken to write it!